# TerrForm AWS Network Load Balancer Assign a single subnet for each availability zone used

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

First, thank you all for your help with this.

I am new to Terraform and I am working on a project to automate the deployment of an AWS infrastructure in a specific way. The architecture of the AWS infrastructure is one VPC, one public subnet, and 2 private subnets. NAT-GW, Bastion Host, and a Network Load Balancer are deployed in the public subnet.

I did not specify a specific availability zone when creating the subnet. This is because I have faced an issue before, with the AWS region not having enough capacity for the resources, so I have decided to leave it open and not specify a specific availability zone.

This means that the public subnet (having the Load Balancer) can be in AZ-1 and the private subnet can be in AZ-2.

This is causing me an issue, as when I create the Network Load Balancer, I need to assign the public and private subnets but if the subnets are in the same availability zone, then this will fail.

```
Error: creating ELBv2 network Load Balancer (demo-nlb-01): InvalidConfigurationRequest: A load balancer cannot be attached to multiple subnets in the same Availability Zone
│   status code: 400, request id: 3a2746dd-135d-453f-abcb-577834ad6a76
│
│   with aws_lb.nlb-01,
│   on 09-load-balancer.tf line 11, in resource "aws_lb" "nlb-01":
│   11: resource "aws_lb" "nlb-01" {
│
```

Also, I need to attach an EIP to this Network Load Balancer, and to do so in TerraForm you should use the `subnet_mapping` and to assign subnets you need to use `subnets` and you can not define both in the same TerraForm AWS LB module.

Here is my TerraForm so far

```
# Create the public subnet resource
resource "aws_subnet" "pub-sub-01" {
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main-lab-vpc.id
  cidr_block              = "10.10.1.0/24"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true

  tags = {
    Name       = "demo-pub-sub-01"
  }
}

# Create the private management subnet resource
resource "aws_subnet" "priv-mgmt-sub-01" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main-lab-vpc.id
  cidr_block = "10.10.10.0/24"

  tags = {
    Name       = "demo-priv-mgmt-sub-01"
  }
}

# Create the first private pord subnet resource
resource "aws_subnet" "priv-pord-sub-01" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main-lab-vpc.id
  cidr_block = "10.10.11.0/24"

  tags = {
    Name       = "demo-priv-prod-sub-01"
  }
}

#-----------------------------------------------

# Create Network Load Balancer and assign the EIP to it
resource "aws_lb" "nlb-01" {
  name                             = "demo-nlb-01"
  load_balancer_type               = "network"
  internal                         = false
  enable_cross_zone_load_balancing = true
  subnets                          = [aws_subnet.pub-sub-01.id, aws_subnet.priv-mgmt-sub-01.id, aws_subnet.priv-pord-sub-01.id]
  security_groups                  = [aws_security_group.pub-sg-01.id]

  #subnet_mapping {
  #  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.pub-sub-01.id
  #  allocation_id = aws_eip.lb-eip.id
  #}

  tags = {
    Name       = "demo-nlb-01"
  }

}
```